# proving cartesian product is distributive over unions and intersections

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

I had to prove this:

Let $A$, $B$, and $C$ be sets. Then, $A \times (B \Delta C) = (A \times B) \Delta (A \times C)$.

By the definition of symmetric difference, we know that
$$B \Delta C= (B \Delta C) \cup (C \Delta B).$$
So, we can expand the LHS of this theorem to get 
$$A \times ( (B \Delta C) \cup (C \Delta B) ).$$
Therefore,
\begin{align}
A \times (B \Delta C) &= A \times ( (B \Delta C) \cup (C \Delta B) ) \\
&= (A \times (B \Delta C)) \cup (A \times (C \Delta B)) \\
&= ((A \times B) \Delta (A \times C)) \cup ((A \times C) \Delta (A \times B)) \\
&= (A \times B) \Delta (A \times C).
\end{align}
So, the LHS = RHS.

But I'm not sure how to show that cartesian products are actually distributive over unions and intersections?

Comment: Whenever it is a result that you'd like to hold for some other proof, remember: it might not be true!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I write $a$, I mean it to refer to something in $A$. (This saves space.)

$$A \times (B \cup C) = \{(a,x): x \in B \cup C \}$$
$$(A \times B) \cup (A \times C) = \{(a,x): x \in B \} \cup \{(a,x): x \in C\}$$

(Inclusion of first into second is clear; as is inclusion of second into first.)

---

How about intersection?
$$A \times (B \cap C) = \{(a,x) : x \in B \cap C\}$$
$$(A \times B) \cap (A \times C) = \{ (a,x): x \in B\} \cap \{(a,x): x \in C \}$$

Inclusion of first into second: if we have $(a,x)$ where $x \in B \cap C$, then $(a,x) \in A \times B$ and $(a,x) \in A \times C$, so we have that direction.

For the other direction, take $(a, x)$ where $x \in B$ and also $x \in C$ (so $(a,x)$ is in both components of the intersection). Then $(a,x)$ is in $A \times (B \cap C)$, so we're done again.